# Very slow git network commands

Tags: git, github

I have a git installed on new Windows 7 machine, behind corporate proxy.
(All described below is correct also for GitHub client)
I configured it to use local cntlm proxy to work correctly with GitHub.
Then I try to use `git pull`, `git push` etc. I need to wait 1-2 minutes before git starts to download or upload any information.

All local commands works fine.

I reproduce this issue on very small project.

I know that there are other questions about "very slow git", but in this questions users say about seconds of delay, in my situation 1-2 minutes. This problem reproduced on 3 Windows 7 machines in my office.

My previous Windows XP machine works correctly.
My Windows 8.1 machine works correctly.

Is there any dependency that can solve my problem?
(I already try reinstallation.)